# Being for background information

Tags: meaning, passive-voice, subordinate-clauses

Being can be used as a subordinate clause or a noun clause to give explanatory background information. Consider my sentence in this context :

> *Being entertained by smartphones and gaming gadgets, children these days have turned their backs on real-life entertainment such as playing sports, listening to stories and spending time with family members.*

Is this sentence correct? All the sentences I am trying to make are subordinate clause sentences.

Can you give an example of a noun clause using *being* as a background information provider?

Comment: I have modified your example slightly to correct small idiomatic errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of the clause `Being entertained by smartphones and gaming gadgets` is correct in your sentence. Here is an example of a noun clause using 'being'.

> *Being constantly entertained by smartphones and gadgets* could have serious consequences for children.

The clause in your sentence seems to be a participle clause:

- [https://www.englishgrammar.org/uses-of-being/#:~:text=Being%20in%20participle%20clauses,couldn't%20watch%20the%20show](https://www.englishgrammar.org/uses-of-being/#:%7E:text=Being%20in%20participle%20clauses,couldn%27t%20watch%20the%20show)
- [https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/intermediate-to-upper-intermediate/participle-clauses#:~:text=Participle%20clauses%20enable%20us%20to,having%20walked%2C%20etc](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/intermediate-to-upper-intermediate/participle-clauses#:%7E:text=Participle%20clauses%20enable%20us%20to,having%20walked%2C%20etc)

Comment: @kandyman..its so similar to my subordinate clause but what is the difference?

Comment: An entire noun clause can be replaced by 'it' and still remains grammatical. In your sentence, the clause appears to be a participle clause which means 'because'. [links added to post]